# Is there a way to identify the exchange server version from the EWS URL?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there a way to identify the version of the exchange server? And if it's an O365 or on-prem from the EWS URL?

The data we have is:

```
setting1 = {"ewsURL": "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx", "clientid": "<someid>", "tenantkey": "<somekey>", "relaxed": false, "serverSubtype": 0, "keyStore": "grid"};
setting2 = {"ewsURL": "https://<servername_or_ip>/EWS/Exchange.asmx", "adminUser": "<someuser>", "adminPassword": "<somepassword>", "relaxed": false};
```

Answer (score 0):

No with Office365 you know it's the latest but for anything else you need to either make and Autodiscover request and check the version of make any other request (eg Get the Inbox or convertId) and check the ServerVersionInfo in the response